# Segmentation fault to get some points

Tags: python, ipython

```
del_between=raw_input('Do you want to delete all the points between two points? input "N" or "Y"')
if del_between=="N" or del_between=="n":
    print "You have choosen NOT to delete all the points between two points."
if del_between=="Y" or del_between=="y" :
    print "Please click the first bad point and the last bad point to choose the range of the bad points"
    between_badpoints=ginput(n=2)
    print between_badpoints
    index_between_badpoints=[]
    for i in range(len(between_badpoints)):
         index_between_badpoints.append(int(np.interp(between_badpoints[i][0],jd2,range(len(jd2)))))
    print index_between_badpoints
    index_betweens=[]
    for i in range(sorted(index_between_badpoints)[0],sorted(index_between_badpoints)[1]+1):
         index_betweens.append(i)
    print index_betweens
    for i in index_betweens[::-1]:
         del lat[i],lon[i],time[i],yeardays[i],depth[i],temp[i]
```

This program is try to delete all points between two points which are collected.the question is when I try to run this program, it will show segmentation fault.

When I click to chose point, it will raise an exception "segmentation fault", so I think the problem maybe focus on this line 'between_badpoints=ginput(n=2)'.but I don't understand why it's wrong.

(I have used this 'ginput' command in this same program and it worked well, and then I delete the ginput variable and used it again like this, it couldn't work.)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the error message you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out.This is the second time I use ginput in this program,but I haven't created a new figure.After add 'fig=plt.figure()'line,every step goes well.May be each figure can only use ginput one time.